# MAGENTO - Registration form (+validation and callback) outside magento files?

Tags: magento, external, registration

I'm trying to integrate a php file inside an aplication that gives users the posibility to register an account. This account has to be registered inside a magento store.

This is what i have to this momment:

```
    <?php
    require_once '../../../app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

    // get layout object  
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

    //get block object  
    $block = $layout->createBlock('core/template');
    //print_r(get_class_methods(get_class($block))); <- use for seeing classes
    $block = $block->setTemplate('customer/form/register.phtml')->renderView();
    echo $block;
    ?>
```

This code renders the registration form but stops when he is showing the input fields. I tried with "mini.login.phtml" and it renderes correctly. I'm not very good at Magento, or english. I can provide any other information if necessary.

Any help will be appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong block type when dynamically creating the block. Try using this:

createBlock('customer/form_register')

Comment: I have alreaady used this block but it throws me a fatal error. Also tried to repair this error but nothing!

     Fatal error: Call to a member function setTitle() on a non-object in ../app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Register.php on line 36

Comment: This is because the block tries to load the Head block and set the page title. You could get around this by first creating a block of type page/html_head and ensuring that it's layout name is head. Alternatively, you could overwrite the Register block so that it doesn't call the _prepareLayout method, which is causing your problems

Comment: I'll try the first method to see if it's working. The second one i already tried and broke my website registration form (magento's). I'll come back with change info.

Comment: Well, surprisingly, the second method worked now! I removed the prepare layout function from block and it renders my registration form correctly. The first method didn't work, it threw the fatal error again. I created a block of type paget/html_head and i echo'd it "$head->getCssJsHtml();" into <head></head> and didn't worked.